# What does "org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: OK" mean?

Tags: https, httpresponse, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using Apache Http Client 4.2.
Application tries to connect to remote HTTPS destination, but fails with this stacktrace:

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: OK
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:68)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:945)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:919)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:910)
```

Web says nothing about this particular exception. Does anybody knows what could this "HttpResponseException: OK" mean?

Thanks.

Comment: The exception is raised when the server returns a non-success HTTP response code. "OK" is the Http Status Line returned by the server. Not very descriptive in your case. You need to take a look at the status code, too (which hopefully is more meaningful), and possibly the response body.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I was thinking that this "OK" message is something that is produced by http client. But I think, you are right, it's a response from the remote system. I will examine status code and headers. Thanks.